# Unexpected leading characters in downloaded CSS

Tags: asp.net, css

I am developing an ASP.Net web application.

Some of my users' browsers are rendering un-styled pages (i.e. it appears that the style sheet is not being used).

When I browse to the css file from one of these users' browsers, I see unexpected leading characters.

The following example is from a user using IE7 (I too am using IE7, but I don't get this problem)...

```
Ã¯Â»Â¿@import url("aa.reset.css"); @import url("aa.core.css"); @import url("aa.header.css"); @import url("aa.middle.css"); @import url("aa.footer.css"); @import url("aa.misc.css"); @import url("Pager.css");
```

I suspect that the characters "Ã¯Â»Â¿" may be the source of my issue.

When I browse from my machine, I see

```
@import url("aa.reset.css");
@import url("aa.core.css");
@import url("aa.header.css");
@import url("aa.middle.css");
@import url("aa.footer.css");
@import url("aa.misc.css");
@import url("Pager.css");
```

Any ideas anyone?

Thanks

Sandy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you saving this file as UTF8? Check your editor to see if it has an option to save as UTF8 without [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte-order_mark)